How to create a circular grouped and stacked bar chart in R
Trying to create a circular stacked bar chart, like this one: https://r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html . But that also includes subgroups. I'm unable to create a chart that is both stacked and grouped more than once.
So there are multiple categories here. For this plot I would like to: 1. Group by 'group' column into 3 different categories 2. each of the three categories will be grouped into different carbon chain lengths (so this would be a grouped barplot) and 3. further group by functional group within each grouped barplot
I'd like this to be measured by summarise(n=n()) in %. Right now I have the type of chart I like, I just need to make it into the circle.
My data looks like this:
structure(list(`No of Carbon` = c(9, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 8, 9, 8, 
8, 13, 4, 6, 10, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 8, 11, 6, 2, 9, 8, 4, 14, 12, 
4, 4, 10, 6, 6, 9, 10, 9, 10, 4, 8, 6), `Functional Group` = c("Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Sulfonate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", 
"Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", 
"Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", 
"Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate"), `PFAS Type` = structure(c(28L, 
28L, 20L, 4L, 26L, 19L, 30L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 41L, 18L, 27L, 7L, 
27L, 24L, 26L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 17L, 27L, 36L, 28L, 30L, 19L, 40L, 
22L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 27L, 14L, 28L, 23L, 28L, 20L, 19L, 30L, 27L
), levels = c("4:2 Cl-PFESA", "4:2 FTS", "6:2 Cl-PFESA", "6:2 FTS", 
"6:2 H-PFESA", "8:2 Cl-PFESA", "8:2 FTS", "ADONA", "FBSA", "FHxSA", 
"FOSA", "FOSAA", "GenX", "HFPO-DA", "HFPO-TA", "N-Et-FOSAA", 
"N-Me-FOSAA", "PFBA", "PFBS", "PFDA", "PFDDA", "PFDoA", "PFDS", 
"PFHpA", "PFHpS", "PFHxA", "PFHxS", "PFNA", "PFNS", "PFOA", "PFONDS", 
"PFONS", "PFOS", "PFOSA", "PFOUDS", "PFPA", "PFPeA", "PFPeS", 
"PFTDA", "PFTeDA", "PFTrDA", "PFUA", "PFUdA", "PFUnA"), class = "factor"), 
    concentrations = c(0.45, 5.9, 0.83, 1.2, 0.82, 2.04, 12.7, 
    1.15, 2.71, 156, 0.71, 5.37, 0.00007, 0.04, 0.35, 0.19, 2.95, 
    0.26, 2.63, 0.96, 0.33, 117.18, 16, 0.4, 24, 0.45, 1.33, 
    3.57, 3.6, 3.15, 0.02, 0.97, 1.38, 0.34, 0.22, 1.34, 3.3, 
    5.27, 3.69, 3.54), carbon_chain = c("Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", 
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", 
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS"), group = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("rain", "stormwater", 
    "surface"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), na.action = structure(c(`7` = 7L, 
`8` = 8L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, `13` = 13L, 
`14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `16` = 16L, `17` = 17L, `18` = 18L, `19` = 19L, 
`20` = 20L, `21` = 21L, `22` = 22L, `42` = 42L, `43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, 
`59` = 59L, `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, 
`65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, 
`80` = 80L, `81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, 
`86` = 86L, `87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `94` = 94L, `95` = 95L, `96` = 96L, 
`97` = 97L, `98` = 98L, `99` = 99L, `100` = 100L, `101` = 101L, 
`102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `106` = 106L, 
`107` = 107L, `108` = 108L, `109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `136` = 136L, 
`137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, `139` = 139L, `140` = 140L, `141` = 141L, 
`142` = 142L, `143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, `146` = 146L, 
`147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, `149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L, 
`152` = 152L, `153` = 153L, `154` = 154L, `157` = 157L, `158` = 158L, 
`159` = 159L, `160` = 160L, `161` = 161L, `162` = 162L, `163` = 163L, 
`164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `166` = 166L, `167` = 167L, `168` = 168L, 
`169` = 169L, `170` = 170L, `171` = 171L, `172` = 172L, `173` = 173L, 
`174` = 174L, `175` = 175L, `176` = 176L, `180` = 180L, `181` = 181L, 
`182` = 182L, `183` = 183L, `184` = 184L, `185` = 185L, `186` = 186L, 
`187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, `191` = 191L, 
`192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, `195` = 195L, `196` = 196L, 
`197` = 197L, `198` = 198L, `200` = 200L, `201` = 201L, `202` = 202L, 
`203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `205` = 205L, `206` = 206L, `207` = 207L, 
`208` = 208L, `209` = 209L, `210` = 210L, `211` = 211L, `212` = 212L, 
`213` = 213L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, `216` = 216L, `217` = 217L, 
`218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, `220` = 220L, `224` = 224L, `225` = 225L, 
`226` = 226L, `227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `230` = 230L, 
`231` = 231L, `232` = 232L, `233` = 233L, `234` = 234L, `235` = 235L, 
`236` = 236L, `237` = 237L, `238` = 238L, `239` = 239L, `240` = 240L, 
`241` = 241L, `242` = 242L, `248` = 248L, `249` = 249L, `250` = 250L, 
`251` = 251L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, `254` = 254L, `255` = 255L, 
`256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `259` = 259L, `260` = 260L, 
`261` = 261L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, `264` = 264L, `270` = 270L, 
`271` = 271L, `272` = 272L, `273` = 273L, `274` = 274L, `275` = 275L, 
`276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `278` = 278L, `279` = 279L, `280` = 280L, 
`281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, `285` = 285L, 
`286` = 286L, `290` = 290L, `291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, 
`294` = 294L, `295` = 295L, `296` = 296L, `297` = 297L, `298` = 298L, 
`299` = 299L, `300` = 300L, `301` = 301L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, 
`304` = 304L, `305` = 305L, `306` = 306L, `307` = 307L, `308` = 308L, 
`311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `313` = 313L, `314` = 314L, `315` = 315L, 
`316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, `320` = 320L, 
`321` = 321L, `322` = 322L, `323` = 323L, `324` = 324L, `325` = 325L, 
`326` = 326L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, `329` = 329L, `330` = 330L, 
`333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `336` = 336L, `337` = 337L, 
`338` = 338L, `339` = 339L, `340` = 340L, `341` = 341L, `342` = 342L, 
`343` = 343L, `344` = 344L, `345` = 345L, `346` = 346L, `347` = 347L, 
`348` = 348L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, `351` = 351L, `352` = 352L, 
`355` = 355L, `356` = 356L, `357` = 357L, `358` = 358L, `359` = 359L, 
`360` = 360L, `361` = 361L, `362` = 362L, `363` = 363L, `364` = 364L, 
`365` = 365L, `366` = 366L, `367` = 367L, `368` = 368L, `369` = 369L, 
`370` = 370L, `371` = 371L, `372` = 372L, `373` = 373L, `374` = 374L
), class = "omit"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

what I have made so far
summary_fig1 <- figure1_edit %>% 
  group_by(group, carbon_chain, `Functional Group`) %>% 
  summarise(N=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=carbon_chain, y=N, fill=`Functional Group`)) + 
  geom_bar(position='fill', stat = 'identity',color='black') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_grid(~group)

I'm unsure of the next step and have tried to follow the tutorial from https://r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html but get confused since I have multiple categorical groups and want to show it by %n. I am relatively new at this so still figuring everything out! Thank you!
Update: I was able to use this code with a small edit to coord_polar:
  summarise(N = n(), .by = c(group, carbon_chain, `Functional Group`)) |> 
  mutate(
    prop = N / sum(N), 
    x = paste0(group, "\n", carbon_chain),
    .by = c(group, carbon_chain)
    ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = prop, fill = `Functional Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", color = "black") +
  geom_label(aes(label = scales::percent(prop, 1)), fill = "white",
             show.legend = F, position = "fill", size = 2) +
 #coord_radial(rotate_angle = TRUE) + 
  coord_polar() + 
#guides(theta = guide_axis_theta(angle = 0)) + 
  ylim(c(-1, NA)) + # hole size
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) ```

I'm just having trouble with the labels now. [The prop labels are not in the correct spaces and I would like to change the group labels to be on the inner circle rather than the outside of the circle][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/00fHd.png


"The setup of the chart I would like" and "what I have made so far" are the same. I guess the first one is wrong.


Your dput() is missing some lines, 2) running your code on your (corrected) example data does not result in the example plot you posted. Please update your question with the correct data required to reproduce your plot.


Are you looking for something along these lines?
Maybe adapt this and post another question (with a reprex of what you have so far) if you get stuck further?
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(
  `No of Carbon` = c(
    9, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 8, 9, 8,
    8, 13, 4, 6, 10, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 8, 11, 6, 2, 9, 8, 4, 14, 12,
    4, 4, 10, 6, 6, 9, 10, 9, 10, 4, 8, 6
  ), `Functional Group` = c(
    "Carboxylate",
    "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate",
    "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate",
    "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Sulfonate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate",
    "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate",
    "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate",
    "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate",
    "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate",
    "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate", "Carboxylate", "Sulfonate"
  ), `PFAS Type` = structure(c(
    28L,
    28L, 20L, 4L, 26L, 19L, 30L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 41L, 18L, 27L, 7L,
    27L, 24L, 26L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 17L, 27L, 36L, 28L, 30L, 19L, 40L,
    22L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 27L, 14L, 28L, 23L, 28L, 20L, 19L, 30L, 27L
  ), levels = c(
    "4:2 Cl-PFESA", "4:2 FTS", "6:2 Cl-PFESA", "6:2 FTS",
    "6:2 H-PFESA", "8:2 Cl-PFESA", "8:2 FTS", "ADONA", "FBSA", "FHxSA",
    "FOSA", "FOSAA", "GenX", "HFPO-DA", "HFPO-TA", "N-Et-FOSAA",
    "N-Me-FOSAA", "PFBA", "PFBS", "PFDA", "PFDDA", "PFDoA", "PFDS",
    "PFHpA", "PFHpS", "PFHxA", "PFHxS", "PFNA", "PFNS", "PFOA", "PFONDS",
    "PFONS", "PFOS", "PFOSA", "PFOUDS", "PFPA", "PFPeA", "PFPeS",
    "PFTDA", "PFTeDA", "PFTrDA", "PFUA", "PFUdA", "PFUnA"
  ), class = "factor"),
  concentrations = c(
    0.45, 5.9, 0.83, 1.2, 0.82, 2.04, 12.7,
    1.15, 2.71, 156, 0.71, 5.37, 0.00007, 0.04, 0.35, 0.19, 2.95,
    0.26, 2.63, 0.96, 0.33, 117.18, 16, 0.4, 24, 0.45, 1.33,
    3.57, 3.6, 3.15, 0.02, 0.97, 1.38, 0.34, 0.22, 1.34, 3.3,
    5.27, 3.69, 3.54
  ), carbon_chain = c(
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS",
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS",
    "Long Chain PFAS", "Long Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS",
    "Short Chain PFAS", "Short Chain PFAS"
  ), group = structure(c(
    3L,
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L,
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
  ), levels = c(
    "rain", "stormwater",
    "surface"
  ), class = "factor")
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), na.action = structure(c(
  `7` = 7L,
  `8` = 8L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, `13` = 13L,
  `14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `16` = 16L, `17` = 17L, `18` = 18L, `19` = 19L,
  `20` = 20L, `21` = 21L, `22` = 22L, `42` = 42L, `43` = 43L, `44` = 44L,
  `59` = 59L, `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L,
  `65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L,
  `80` = 80L, `81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L,
  `86` = 86L, `87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `94` = 94L, `95` = 95L, `96` = 96L,
  `97` = 97L, `98` = 98L, `99` = 99L, `100` = 100L, `101` = 101L,
  `102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `106` = 106L,
  `107` = 107L, `108` = 108L, `109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `136` = 136L,
  `137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, `139` = 139L, `140` = 140L, `141` = 141L,
  `142` = 142L, `143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, `146` = 146L,
  `147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, `149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L,
  `152` = 152L, `153` = 153L, `154` = 154L, `157` = 157L, `158` = 158L,
  `159` = 159L, `160` = 160L, `161` = 161L, `162` = 162L, `163` = 163L,
  `164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `166` = 166L, `167` = 167L, `168` = 168L,
  `169` = 169L, `170` = 170L, `171` = 171L, `172` = 172L, `173` = 173L,
  `174` = 174L, `175` = 175L, `176` = 176L, `180` = 180L, `181` = 181L,
  `182` = 182L, `183` = 183L, `184` = 184L, `185` = 185L, `186` = 186L,
  `187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, `191` = 191L,
  `192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, `195` = 195L, `196` = 196L,
  `197` = 197L, `198` = 198L, `200` = 200L, `201` = 201L, `202` = 202L,
  `203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `205` = 205L, `206` = 206L, `207` = 207L,
  `208` = 208L, `209` = 209L, `210` = 210L, `211` = 211L, `212` = 212L,
  `213` = 213L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, `216` = 216L, `217` = 217L,
  `218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, `220` = 220L, `224` = 224L, `225` = 225L,
  `226` = 226L, `227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `230` = 230L,
  `231` = 231L, `232` = 232L, `233` = 233L, `234` = 234L, `235` = 235L,
  `236` = 236L, `237` = 237L, `238` = 238L, `239` = 239L, `240` = 240L,
  `241` = 241L, `242` = 242L, `248` = 248L, `249` = 249L, `250` = 250L,
  `251` = 251L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, `254` = 254L, `255` = 255L,
  `256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `259` = 259L, `260` = 260L,
  `261` = 261L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, `264` = 264L, `270` = 270L,
  `271` = 271L, `272` = 272L, `273` = 273L, `274` = 274L, `275` = 275L,
  `276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `278` = 278L, `279` = 279L, `280` = 280L,
  `281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, `285` = 285L,
  `286` = 286L, `290` = 290L, `291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L,
  `294` = 294L, `295` = 295L, `296` = 296L, `297` = 297L, `298` = 298L,
  `299` = 299L, `300` = 300L, `301` = 301L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L,
  `304` = 304L, `305` = 305L, `306` = 306L, `307` = 307L, `308` = 308L,
  `311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `313` = 313L, `314` = 314L, `315` = 315L,
  `316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, `320` = 320L,
  `321` = 321L, `322` = 322L, `323` = 323L, `324` = 324L, `325` = 325L,
  `326` = 326L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, `329` = 329L, `330` = 330L,
  `333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `336` = 336L, `337` = 337L,
  `338` = 338L, `339` = 339L, `340` = 340L, `341` = 341L, `342` = 342L,
  `343` = 343L, `344` = 344L, `345` = 345L, `346` = 346L, `347` = 347L,
  `348` = 348L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, `351` = 351L, `352` = 352L,
  `355` = 355L, `356` = 356L, `357` = 357L, `358` = 358L, `359` = 359L,
  `360` = 360L, `361` = 361L, `362` = 362L, `363` = 363L, `364` = 364L,
  `365` = 365L, `366` = 366L, `367` = 367L, `368` = 368L, `369` = 369L,
  `370` = 370L, `371` = 371L, `372` = 372L, `373` = 373L, `374` = 374L
), class = "omit"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df |> 
  summarise(N = n(), .by = c(group, carbon_chain, `Functional Group`)) |> 
  arrange(desc(`Functional Group`), carbon_chain, group) |> 
  mutate(
    prop = N / sum(N), 
    label_y = cumsum(prop),
    x = paste0(group, "\n", carbon_chain),
    .by = c(group, carbon_chain)
  ) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = prop, fill = `Functional Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", color = "black") +
  geom_label(aes(y = label_y, label = scales::percent(prop, 1)), fill = "white",
             show.legend = F, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 2) +
  coord_radial(rotate_angle = T) + 
  # coord_polar() + # if preferred
  guides(theta = guide_axis_theta(angle = 0)) + 
  ylim(c(-1, NA)) + # hole size
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dotted"),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )


Created on 2024-04-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Hi, thank you! This was great. I did have some trouble with labels and had to change a bit and am not sure how to proceed. I just added an update to my post.

Updated to fix the label positioning (should also work with coord_polar if you prefer that). You can tweak the positioning with position_fill(vjust = 0.5) where 0.5 is currently centred. Not immediately obvious how to put the outer text in the middle. Thought scale_x_discrete(position = "top") might work. Can I suggest you post a completely new focused question for that?
